# MS Excel sort column containing non-latin characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, unicode, multilingual

Is it possible to sort a column containing text strings in Excel when the script is non-latin, e.g. cyrillic?

If so, how?

```
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+  
|                 CORRECT ORDER                  |               A-Z SORT IN EXCEL                |  
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+  
| 3M – Шинэ Зеланд                               | 3M – Шинэ Зеланд                               |  
| Бристол Майэрз – Энэтхэг                       | Koника Минолта – Австрали                      |  
| Бупа Эрүүл мэндийн даатгал – Tайланд           | Maэрск Шипинг  – Шинэ Зеланд                   |  
| Бхарти Телевенчерз Лтд. – Энэтхэг              | Moторола – Энэтхэг                             |  
| ГлаксоСмитКлайн – Шинэ Зеланд                  | Oлимпус Оптикал – Япон                         |  
| Ди Эйч Эл – Австрали                           | Toёота Файнэншл – Австрали                     |  
| Жeнeрaл Moторз – Энэтхэг                       | Tайкo Хэлткэйр- Сингапур                       |  
| Жэй-Ви-Си – Япон                               | Бристол Майэрз – Энэтхэг                       |  
| Инграм Микро – Австрали                        | Бупа Эрүүл мэндийн даатгал – Tайланд           |  
| Koника Минолта – Австрали                      | Бхарти Телевенчерз Лтд. – Энэтхэг              |  
| Кап Жемини – Энэтхэг                           | ГлаксоСмитКлайн – Шинэ Зеланд                  |  
| Ковансис компани – Энэтхэг                     | Ди Эйч Эл – Австрали                           |  
| Лексмарк – Австрали                            | Жeнeрaл Moторз – Энэтхэг                       |  
| Maэрск Шипинг  – Шинэ Зеланд                   | Жэй-Ви-Си – Япон                               |  
| Moторола – Энэтхэг                             | Инграм Микро – Австрали                        |  
| Нeстле Глобал – Австрали                       | Кап Жемини – Энэтхэг                           |  
| Нокиа – Япон                                   | Ковансис компани – Энэтхэг                     |  
| Oлимпус Оптикал – Япон                         | Лексмарк – Австрали                            |  
| Рийдерз Дайжест – Австрали                     | Нeстле Глобал – Австрали                       |  
| Си Ай Жи Ай Инк – Филиппин                     | Нокиа – Япон                                   |  
| Стандард энд Пуэрз – Япон                      | Рийдерз Дайжест – Австрали                     |  
| Статистикийн товчоо – Австрали                 | Си Ай Жи Ай Инк – Филиппин                     |  
| Toёота Файнэншл – Австрали                     | Стандард энд Пуэрз – Япон                      |  
| Tайкo Хэлткэйр- Сингапур                       | Статистикийн товчоо – Австрали                 |  
| Федерал зочид буудал, амралты газар – Австрали | Федерал зочид буудал, амралты газар – Австрали |  
| Форд – Австрали                                | Форд – Австрали                                |  
| Хана семикондактор – Тайланд                   | Хана семикондактор – Тайланд                   |  
| Хэсс ойл энд газ – Maлайз                      | Хэсс ойл энд газ – Maлайз                      |  
| Эй Би Эн Aмро – Австрали                       | Эй Би Эн Aмро – Австрали                       |  
| Эй Эм Ди – Сингапур                            | Эй Эм Ди – Сингапур                            |  
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Excel will sort the data with cyrillic or other script used without complaint.  Or do you have a question about exactly how this sort occurs, or a specific claim that it is doing it incorrectly?  Please provide a specific ecample.

Comment: The problem occurred because the character sets were mixed, which was hard to spot, the Latin K was used instead of the cyrillic (alt-01050)

Comment: So, is it fixed now, if you replace latin K with the correct symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it is possible to sort. 1st.. detect and replace all the 'latinized' cyrillic letters . Let say your list start at A2 cell, put =left(A2) in F2, =CODE(F2) in G2 and =UNICODE(F2) in H2 and drag downwards.

in you see the same value in column G and H, then the character is actually a latin instead of Cyrillic. Eg. the kappa copied from [unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/039A/) will show code() of 63 and Unicode of 922. while the one in your list shows 75 for both.. (so.. it is not the recognized cyrillic kappa).

That how you may detect if it was the correct letters. (AFAIK, in your list the letter M, O, T, is also latinized. )